# Add/Edit multiple resources in one form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-admin

I am trying to manage two linked resources in one `Edit` > `SimpleForm`. The relationship between both resources is a one-to-one between two tables.

For instance, let's say we have these two tables:

### User

- id
- email
- password
- name
- address_id

### Address

- id
- street
- number
- postcode
- country_name

I'm using react-admin for managing records from these two tables from PostgreSQL through graphql (using [hasura](https://hasura.io/)). There are a few options in term of data provider for hasura and graphql.

The first one I tried [ra-data-hasura](https://github.com/hasura/ra-data-hasura) works using the [`/v1/query`](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/api-reference/schema-metadata-api/index.html#endpoint) REST API endpoint of hasura. The documentation for this endpoint is lacking.

I also tried [ra-data-graphql-simple](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-data-graphql-simple), and [ra-data-hasura-graphql](https://github.com/steams/ra-data-hasura-graphql).

As far as I can tell, none support querying relations/foreign key tables in one query. Therefore none of these provider can retrieve foreign keys tables and embed the result directly in the main object response json.

Just to be clear, I mean returning something like this for user:

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "name": "John Smith",
 "email": "john.smith@gmail.com",
 "password": "password",
 "address": {
   "id": 145,
   "street": "High Street",
   "number": "25b",
   "postcode": "EC2 5FG",
   "country_name": "United Kingdom"
 }
}
```

Therefore I am trying to retrieve the `address` record on the `Edit` form using a separate query, which I did (probably not in the best way, feel free to suggest a better version):

```
import { useGetOne, Loading, Error } from 'react-admin';

const FetchRelated = ({ record, reference, source, children }) => {
    const { data, loading, error } = useGetOne(reference, record[source]);
    if (loading) return <Loading />;
    if (error) return <Error />;
    if (!data) return null;

    // this is the only way I found to be able to populate the fields in the form with the address data
    record[reference] = data;

    return <React.Fragment>{children}</React.Fragment>;
};

...
import { Edit, SimpleForm, TextInput } from 'react-admin';

...
const UserEdit = props => (
 <Edit {...props}>
  <SimpleForm>
   <FetchRelated reference="address" source="address_id">
    <TextInput source="address.postcode" label="Post Code" />
   </FetchRelated>
  </SimpleForm>
 </Edit>
);
```

Using this, my `record` object now looks like this:

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "name": "John Smith",
 "email": "john.smith@gmail.com",
 "password": "password",
 "address_id": 145,
 "address": {
   "id": 145,
   "street": "High Street",
   "number": "25b",
   "postcode": "EC2 5FG",
   "country_name": "United Kingdom"
 }
}
```

Now I have to take care of the actual edit query. It seems `react-admin` uses [`useEditController`](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/89ac783fd9f961401d1c2e8d4ca4965053ed1d21/packages/ra-core/src/controller/useEditController.ts#L59) for all the requests triggering (both [`useGetOne`](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/89ac783fd9f961401d1c2e8d4ca4965053ed1d21/packages/ra-core/src/controller/useEditController.ts#L67-L75) and [`update`](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/89ac783fd9f961401d1c2e8d4ca4965053ed1d21/packages/ra-core/src/controller/useEditController.ts#L96-L120)). While the update method is passed as `save` attribute to [`SimpleForm`](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/ec8e41e762d516b4caacbc898cfe52cbd8db456f/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/form/SimpleForm.js#L61), it's not passed to [`Toolbar`](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/ec8e41e762d516b4caacbc898cfe52cbd8db456f/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/form/SimpleForm.js#L109-L121), which means (from what I can tell) one cannot override the [`handleSubmit`/`handleSubmitWithRedirect`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#altering-the-form-values-before-submitting) props of `SaveButton` without having to essentially replicate all the code for `update` from `useEditController`.

Ideally, one could override the `handleSubmit` and do one `update` for both resources at once. Using a graphql mutation doing that wouldn't be too much trouble, unfortunately using hasura `/v1/graphql` endpoint doesn't provide a way to [update relations](https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/pull/3852) in one query. Therefore we need to do two queries, which is fine.

Ideally I would want to re-use the existing `update` method to update the `user` record, and add another update call for the `address`.

What is the best possible approach to achieve something like this?

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-final-form';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Toolbar, SaveButton, DeleteButton, useMutation } from 'react-admin';

const RelatedSaveButton = ({ resourceName, id, handleSubmitWithRedirect, ...props }) => {
  const form = useForm();
  const stateData = useSelector(
        state =>
             state.admin.resources[resourceName]
                 ? state.admin.resources[resourceName].data
                 : null,
         [resourceName]
     );
  const [update] = useMutation();
  const handleSave = useCallback((values, redirect) => {
    const params = {type: 'update', resource: resourceName, payload: {id: id, data: values[resourceName], previousData: stateData}};
    update(params, {onSuccess: response => {
      // doing something here to update `user` using `save` from `useEditController`
      // handleSubmitWithRedirect(redirect);
    }});
  }, [resourceName, stateData, id, update]);

  return <SaveButton {...props} onSave={handleSave} />;
};

const UserToolbar = ({ ...props }) => (
  <Toolbar {...props}>
    <RelatedSaveButton resourceName='address' id={props.record['address_id']} />
    <DeleteButton />
  </Toolbar>
);
```

Comment: First, I don't quite understand why you are not using `ReferenceField` ([docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#referencefield)) for automatically fetching the address and linking to the address edit form. Second, you could write your own adapter to include relations. I have written [one for Postgraphile](https://gist.github.com/hendrikniemann/83648da05161a36e84c0ee4ab61ad605) and you could built on top of that. I myself copied and adjusted this one from a more official one.

Comment: My data provider does not fetch complex fields (I use ReferenceField) but it could be adjusted. Have a look at the `isSimpleField` function that makes a decision whether to fetch a field or not.

Comment: @Herku I'm trying to manage the whole record (i.e. all the fields from the `address` table) as the records are linked into a one-to-one relationship. `ReferenceField` can be used to show one field and `ReferenceInput` is meant to be used for changing the `address_id` field in the `user` table only. You probably meant `ReferenceInput`? I'm not sure how you would link `ReferenceField` and the `TextInput` for all the fields of the address field in the edit form. Have any examples?
I will look into implementing the relations on top of the dataProvider, that sounds like a good idea, thanks.

Comment: Okay, you are actually trying to change the field there. I think I understand your question now a bit better. I guess you could do this update you are describing inside of the data adapter (basically add an if statement checking if the current resource is `user`). Good luck!